# Adding a command line input for testing a method in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console-application, readline

I am writing a program in a C# Console Application and within some of the methods I have Console.ReadLine() and Console.WriteLine(). I want to know how to give the input within a Test Case.

Example:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter account number: ");
        accountNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name: ");
        cStringName = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        name = cStringName;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter balance: ");
        balance = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Date: ");
        dateCreated = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

So basically the method returns a bool saying if an account was created or not. In my test case I want to be able to call this method but in order for it to execute I need to set accountNumber, name, balance, and date. Is there some sort of way of doing this? Or is the best way just to add parameter to the method(which i prefer not to do)?

Comment: Why would you rather not add a parameter? The method that determines whether an account should be created should not know nor care where the data is coming from and therefore should not be tied to the command line. The problem you are having coming up with a testing strategy is a clear indication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the method so that it takes a couple of `Stream` as parameters. Then when you call it in the real program, send in `Console.Out` and `Console.In` as parameters. When calling from your test case, send in some memory streams instead.

When writing this kind of methods and you want to test them, they should not depend directly on the console, but rather on an abstract stream. Then you use *dependency injection* (e.g. passing in the streams as parameters) to be able to substitute the console for a memory stream when testing.